# Giving required inputs to a Python file at different time using a PHP file

Tags: python, php, input

I am going to connect two scripts, one of which is a python file and the other a PHP file. Let's say the python file looks like such as what follows:

###### python_file.py

```py
first_input = input("First input: ")
second_input = input("Second input: ")
```

By running `python3 python_file.py` through the command prompt, there would be something like:

```
First input: 1
Second input: 2
```

But the thing is, I want to read the inputs' text, i.e., "First input: " and "Second input: ", through a PHP script and answer to these inputs proportionally.

One can simply use `system("python3 python_file.py '1' '2'");` but that's not what I'm looking for. The thing is, I am going to send input `1` first, and after that, the PHP file is terminated, send the second input, which is `2`. Note that it is not known when precisely the second input will be sent. So, some functions such as `sleep` won't be helpful. Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think that specific way is not possible:

```py
# write.py
print ("hello")

# read.py
print(input())
print(input())
```

Because we reach the end of file when the script is over:

```
$ python write.py | python read.py 
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\dev\stackoverflow\python\inputs\read.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

But we can use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to create processes and check their output from our python scripts:

```
# advanced_reader.py
import subprocess

byte_output1 = subprocess.check_output(["python", "write.py"])
output1 = str(byte_output1, "utf8")
output2 = input("Second input: ")

print(output1)
print(output2)
```

Which evaluates to

```
$ python advanced_reader.py 
Second input: world
hello

world
```

So you'd just need to replace ["python", "write.py"] with the command and arguments needed to run your PHP script.

(Additionally, you may want to replace some of those excessive newlines, depending on your objective)